# Expo app runs on ios and emulator but not on android device

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, apk, expo

The Expo app will build and run correctly on ios simulator, ios device, and android emulator. but when I build an apk and run on an android device the app freezes after login and will not respond. I'm fairly new to react-native and development in general so I'm not sure what I would be doing wrong?

Comment: What error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the app on debug or release? You can trace the error using logcat on Android Studio or using react-native log-android in a terminal window. That should show you the error message. There are many ways to understand what is happening after you login. Check out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

You can also show us some code, getting your login code would help shed some light on what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with my code. It wasn't login related, but rather because I was using Google Maps API and I didn't have an API key set in app.json for Android.

https://github.com/brentvatne/growler-prowler/commit/3496e69b14adb21eb2025ef9e0719c2edbef2aa2

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @letsGITstupid helped me out to figure out the issue, that's why +1.
However, the real problem was lack of API key in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_KEY"/>
```